# jquery split textarea value by comma and new line

Tags: jquery, split

I have this texarea that i would like to parse its value by comma and new line after keyup of the user. Sample.

INPUT

```
 /*  inside textarea */
   2 water, 4 ice
   6 lemon
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Total # of Items: 3

  Item #               Quantity          Item Name
    1                     2               Water
    2                     4                Ice 
    3                     6               Lemon
```

This is the code so far:

```
$('#$name').keyup(function (event) {
$("#textAreaDiv").show();   
if(event.keyCode == 188){
    $("#textAreaTaggingDetails").html(getItems($('#$name').val().split('\\n'), 'comma'));   
    //console.log("comma press");
}   
else if (event.keyCode == 13) {     
    //console.log("new line press");
    $("#textAreaTaggingDetails").html(getItems($('#$name').val().split(','), 'newLine'));   
}
```

});

```
 function getItems(eachLine, type){     
   var xcontent = "";       
   $("#titleTextAreaTagging").html('Total # of Items: ' + eachLine.length + '<br/>');

   for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {

       var quantity = (eachLine[i]).match(/\d+/);
       var itemName = (eachLine[i]).replace(/[0-9]+/, "");

       xcontent += "<div class=\"col-md-4\"><h6 class=\"text-info mn\" id=\"titleTextAreaTagging\">"+ (i+1) +"</h6></div><div class=\"col-md-4\"><h6 class=\"text-info mn\" id=\"titleTextAreaTagging\">"+ quantity  +"</h6></div><div class=\"col-md-4\"><h6 class=\"text-info mn\" id=\"titleTextAreaTagging\">"+ itemName +"</h6></div>";

  }

  return xcontent;
```

}

With this i can only get correct output with new line but cannot with comma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you can do is, you can replace all new line with comma first then split with comma, this would be easy.

```
str = $('#$name').val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ',');


var partsOfStr = str.split(',');
```